# Searchkick search by multiple words, get results even if they are all scattered between multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

let's say we have:

```
Document.create(title: 'title1', description: 'description1')
```

searching by both:

```
Document.search('title1')
Document.search('description1')
```

finds the result, but searching by:

```
Document.search('title1 description1')
```

gives 0 results

is it possible to adjust the search so that all the words have to be found, but can come from different fields?

The search data looks like this:

```
def search_data
 {
   title:       title,
   description: description
 }
end
```

Comment: Your showing a search_data method which I assume you have in your model, yet your using Document.search ?  However since you say it is working when you are using the single item did you try Document.search('title1', 'description1')   I am not sure what is giving you the .search method.  Are you using Ransack or a search gem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing an upgrade from elasticsearch 1.3.2 to 7.2.0. The app is written with Ruby on Rails and uses the Searchkick gem.

Comment: the search by Document.search('title1 description1') worked on elasticsearch 1.3.2